# Android studio - flutter: No Connected Devices

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have just started with mobile development using flutter, and there is this error when trying to run the default flutter program.

> No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see
> flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions.

- This is a Windows 10 x64 machine.
- Installed Android Studio in - `D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1`
- Installed Android SDK from Android Studio in - `D:\Android\android-sdk`
- Set these system environment variables

  ANDROID_HOME - D:\Android\android-sdk;D:\Android\android-sdk\tools;D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools;D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

  ANDROID_SDK_ROOT - D:\Android\android-sdk;D:\Android\android-sdk\tools;D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools;D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
- Installed Nexus 6 API 28 device & set Emulated Performance Graphics to Hardware GLES-2.0
- Installed `pie Android 9.0 x86` & `pie Android 9.0 x86_64` as I was unsure which one to use. The AVD emulator launches fine with both the OS. (Which one to use?)
- Installed flutter in - `D:\Flutter\flutter`

When I run main.dart, it shows this error:

[image]

When I run flutter doctor in the Android Studio it shows 2 issues:

```
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = D:/Android/android-sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

When I try to run a command in powershell from the flutter directory, it gives this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In environment variables > User Variables, add a new PATH, like: C:\src\flutter\bin

Then restart your machine.

Answer (score 8):

I had faced similar issue, my android studio was detecting the phone but not listing under "Flutter Device Selection".

The problem was I was not configured the Porject SDK

To set up from android studio go to

**File > Project Structure > Project SDK > "available sdk" > Apply**

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution, that worked for me was this :

Go in the terminal and first run -

> **flutter doctor --android-licenses**

If you get no error and the output is something like this :

> All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...

Then check if your emulators are recognized by Android studio (enter this in the terminal):

> **flutter emulators**

This will display the list of emulators you have added. Now enter this in your terminal

> **flutter emulators --launch emulator id**

emulator id is the name of the emulator which you will get from the "flutter emulator" command, so the launch command should be like this :

> **example : flutter emulators --launch Pixel_4a_API_30**

Pixel_4a_API_30 is my emulator's id or the name

as soon as you run this the emulator will launch.

This is what worked for me, hope it works for you!

Good day!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. After relocating the android sdk, you need to run this in cmd/powershell to tell flutter where the Android is:

```
flutter config --android-sdk "your path"
```

Comment: and close terminal and restart this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in the powershell means you did not add the Flutter SDK to your PATH as stated in the [install documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path).

First follow the install documentation to add the Flutter SDK to your PATH, then close any PowerShell windows you have.

Open an emulator.

Open a PowerShell window.

Try to create a test project via the PowerShell like so

```
flutter create <project name>
cd <project name>
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with @rgvi solution.

1. Added new path to PATH variable - `D:\Flutter\flutter\bin`
2. Executed the command `flutter doctor`. This now showed that Android licenses status unknown.
3. Executed the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accepted the licenses.